# Complete definition of 'tx_witness' data structure used in 'tx' data structure

Tags: protocol, network, segregated-witness

I'm reading the [Protocol Documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx) page for the 'tx' data structure and cannot find a completely clear definition of the 'tx_witness' data structure.

After the 'tx_out' table, there is short comment stating that "The TxWitness structure consists of a var_int count of witness data components, followed by (for each witness data component) a var_int length of the component and the raw component data itself."

Could someone post a table, similar to others on the Protocol Documentation page, defining clearly how a 'tx_witness' data structure should be formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bitcoin Core, the `scriptWitness` property (for the `CTxIn` class) is serialized from a `CTransaction` as a `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >`, so I would imagine the serialized version would look something like:

TxWitness:

```
+------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| Field Size |        Description      |       Data Type        |
+------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| 0+         | witness_component count | var_int                |
| ?          | witness_components      | witness_component[]    |
+------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

WitnessComponent:

```
+------------+------------------+-----------+
| Field Size |   Description    | Data Type |
+------------+------------------+-----------+
| 0+         | component length | var_int   |
| ?          | component        | uchar[]   |
+------------+------------------+-----------+
```

References:

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h#L67
- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h#L254
- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script.h#L676